# Unique permutations of list from 2 to N in Python

Tags: python, loops, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to generate a list of permutations in a loop and print for each iteration with output more than two (or write to lines of a file).

Example input list:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Required output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
['two', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two', 'four']
['one', 'two']
['one', 'three']
['one', 'four']
['two', 'three']
['two', 'four']
['three', 'four']
```

This is what I've managed so far (very early in my Python life, please excuse):

```
from itertools import permutations

input = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

def convertTuple(tup): 
    str =  ''.join(tup) 
    return str

while (len(input) > 1):    
    permlist = set(permutations(input))
    for i in permlist:
        print(i)
        i = convertTuple(i)
        outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
        outfile.write(i)
    input = input[:-1]
else:
    print("End of permutation cycle")
```

Which outputs:

```
('two', 'three', 'one', 'four')
('two', 'four', 'one', 'three')
('three', 'two', 'one', 'four')
('four', 'two', 'one', 'three')
('two', 'one', 'three', 'four')
('two', 'one', 'four', 'three')
('three', 'one', 'four', 'two')
('four', 'one', 'three', 'two')
('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
('one', 'two', 'four', 'three')
('three', 'four', 'one', 'two')
('four', 'three', 'one', 'two')
('two', 'three', 'four', 'one')
('two', 'four', 'three', 'one')
('three', 'two', 'four', 'one')
('three', 'four', 'two', 'one')
('four', 'two', 'three', 'one')
('four', 'three', 'two', 'one')
('three', 'one', 'two', 'four')
('four', 'one', 'two', 'three')
('one', 'four', 'two', 'three')
('one', 'three', 'two', 'four')
('one', 'three', 'four', 'two')
('one', 'four', 'three', 'two')
('two', 'three', 'one')
('three', 'two', 'one')
('three', 'one', 'two')
('one', 'two', 'three')
('one', 'three', 'two')
('two', 'one', 'three')
('two', 'one')
('one', 'two')
End of permutation cycle
```

I understand I am going wrong with

```
input = input[:-1]
```

as it just removes the last value in the original list but I can't work out how to get only unique lists back with different numbers of values in each list...

Am I using the wrong part of itertools? Should I be using combinations or something else?

I am seriously stuck so any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't work out how to get only unique lists back with different numbers of values in each list... Should I be using combinations or something else?

Yes, use `combinations` to avoid getting the same set in a different order.

> I understand I am going wrong with `input = input[:-1]`

Right; do not remove items from the candidate set yourself. The functionality you want is already built in.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> help(itertools.combinations)
Help on class combinations in module itertools:

class combinations(builtins.object)
 |  combinations(iterable, r) --> combinations object
 |
 |  Return successive r-length combinations of elements in the iterable.
 |
 |  combinations(range(4), 3) --> (0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,3), (1,2,3)
```

All you need to do is provide the second parameter (it works for `permutations` too). Instead of repeatedly removing elements and finding combinations, just iterate over the possible values for output size.

(Incidentally, there is a slick example for this sort of thing [in the "recipes" section of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): the one labelled `powerset`. The [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of a set is basically the thing you're computing, except also including all the one-element results and the empty result.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ('one','two','three') was an accidental omit from your wanted list, this should do the trick:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

for size in range(2,len(l)+1):
    for i in combinations(l,size):
        print(i)
```